# SFML - Access violation reading location when saving RenderTexture to image 0xC0000005

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml, access-violation

I'm using Visual Studio 2017.
When debugging it points me to line 11

```
texture.getTexture().copyToImage().saveToFile("C:/test.bmp");
```

with an error

> Exception thrown at 0x54B06B9E (sfml-graphics-2.dll) in Project2.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCE6C37F.

I want to save the texture to a .bmp file.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    using namespace sf;
    RenderTexture texture;
    texture.create(800, 600);
    texture.display();
    texture.clear(Color::Black);
    texture.getTexture().copyToImage().saveToFile("C:/test.bmp");

    return 0;
}
```

#### EDIT

As far as we've detected it's the `.saveToFile("C:/test.bmp")` fragment that's causing the issue, the code works fine without it

#### SECOND EDIT

I got SFML packages manually, I include them from a set folder each time I'm making a new project and link the libraries, also added manually through external lib folder

#### THIRD EDIT

After some work I managed to fix the debug libraries and release libraries, now the code throws an exception

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'texture' was corrupted.

A screenshot with the whole output and code:
[image]

Another thing is, when I continue without handling the exception it throws at me this:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00D26859 in Project2.exe: Stack cookie instrumentation code detected a stack-based buffer overrun.

Comment: You could make things easier by breaking up that last line to see exactly which one of those calls is causing the exception.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it's the .saveToFile function as far as I can see, it runs just fine without .saveToFile

Comment: Did you open VS with Administrator rights? Had you try to save it in another folder, less restrictive than `C:`? Maybe `My Documents` or similar could work.

Comment: I haven't used this API, but a function that crashes due to a file not being able to be saved is rather poor.  You would think an error code would be returned on failure (or a C++ exception thrown (not an access violation)).

Comment: @alseether opening as administrator didn't work, changing location to "D:\output\test.bmp" neither

Comment: The [docs](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Image.php#a51537fb667f47cbe80395cfd7f9e72a4) note that "*This function fails if the image is empty.*".  I would think that means that the function returns false, but maybe it means that it invokes undefined behavior?  Try moving the `texture.clear` line before `texture.display`.

Comment: @0x5453 I've tried both configurations, none worked, I also manually created the file under the path, didn't work as well

Comment: How did you install `SFML` libraries? Manually or via NuGet Packages? If manually, as static or as dynamic lib? Did you configure both, debug and release configurations? Would be nice an edit in your question adding all this info ;)

Comment: @alseether I tried to add those informations to the post, but I don't really have an idea if including libraries and headers each time I'm making a new project is static or dynamic, as I'm fairly new to VS. Let's put it that way: I've got VS 2017 installed under C:/Program Files (x86)/Visual Studio and libraries and headers under Documents/OpenGL/lib and Documents/OpenGL/include. Each time I'm making a new project I add their paths in project options in VC++ Directories and link the libraries in linkers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer, the issue was that I wasn't using .dlls compiled for VS 2017, I was using those compiled for 2015 instead, switched them and it works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that you're linking the libraries somehow wrong. 
Ensure you have debug libraries in debug configuration and release ones in release configuration.

Remember, debug libraries usually end with a "d". If you don't set debug libraries correctly, you cannot debug your code and that would explain why you're getting a *poor* error message.

I leave [here](https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=11429.0) a link to SFML forum with someone with a similar issue.

Hope that helps.

---

As side note, for beginners with [sfml](/questions/tagged/sfml) I highly recommend install the library using NuGet packages (right click on your solution -> Manage NuGet packages -> look for SFML -> install)

This works for SFML, not sure for OpenGL.

Comment: So what I did was install the packages via NuGet, but it didn't help much, although I suspect you have to do more things than just press "install".
I'm a beginner in Visual Studio, I have `opengl32.lib, sfml-graphics.lib, sfml-window.lib, sfml-system.lib` under both release and debug configuration, since I didn't have any d-ending libraries I could find

Comment: Actually, it's just that simple. Installing `SFML` via NuGet should create a folder called `packages`, at the level where your solution file is. Inside that folder are all the packages with both versions, Debug and Release. You don't have to worry about linking stuff. Just make sure that you're installing all packages you need, usually `window`, `graphics` and `system` are needed for drawing. Install `audio` or `network` if you want to do music/sounds stuff or network communication respectively.

Comment: I did some tinkering on my PC (I worked on my laptop before) and I got it to work. I'll edit my post with an update